# What is the concept behind javascript parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, parameters

> Let me try to explain my weird confusion

I'm trying to learn about [`d3.js`](https://d3js.org/). I'm seeing a lot of functions with some odd kind of parameters (they look odd at least to me).

```
d3.selectAll("p").style("color", function(d, i) {
  return i % 2 ? "#fff" : "#eee";
});
```

- What is `d` doing here? Why is it passed when it's of no use?
- From where `i` (along with **value**) is getting passed?

Also I was following [Jan's tutorial](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/03/20/tutorial-introduction-to-d3/) and built a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/knagsx1e/). This also has some odd function params:

```
.attr("cy", function(d) {
  return y(d.y)
})
```

```
.delay(function(d, i) {
  return i * del(Math.random())
})
```

- From where `d` (along with **value**) is getting passed?

Comment: `d` is the datum and `i` is the index of that datum. As `i` is the second argument, you have to pass `d`, even if you don't use it. In D3, the first argument is always the datum, the second always the index of the datum and the third one is the node in v4 and the parent's index in v3.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado `datum`? reading this word for the first time. Okey, I believe you got my question. Also I strongly feel that `d` and `i` are not fixed, I can use `e` and `j` - I'm they're mere variables? Correct?

Comment: To add to Gerardo's answer (which it should be), you need 'd' because 'i' is the second parameter of a reusable function definition.  You're not using 'd' in *this* case, but you might another time, so it's always passed.

Comment: What you are seeing here is the way a certain framework is designed and works, pure javascript doesn't have nonsensical arguments that would confuse you like this. When examining the framework you have to see what is passed. The below answers give good insight, just try not to confuse it with javascript having weird parameters, it is the frameworks that make it look like that.

Comment: I'm using datum as singular of data. I believe you English speaking guys use "data" for both singular and plural.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado `datum`? reading this word for the first time. Okey, I believe you got my question. Also I strongly feel that `d` and `i` are not fixed, I can use `e` and `j` - I'm they're mere variables? Correct?

Comment: @student, you are correct: you can call it anyway you want, the only important thing is the order. We call it d because d is the initial letter of data, and I the initial letter of index.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado - How did programmers like you and me decided that first parameter is data, second is index and so on... Is there some kind of documentation as such?

Comment: Mike Bostock made this decision! Here is the API: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/API-Reference

Comment: "*How do programmers like you and me decide*" - in this case, the callback probably initially passed "d" for data first, then someone realised that knowing the index would be helpful so added it as a second parameter so that any existing calls using older versions would still work / would not break (backward compatibility).   In other cases, it might be the most relevant first.   Or, particularly in javascript, optional parameters might be last (in this case if you weren't using 'i', you could do `function(d)` and it would still work).

Comment: @Dellirium What does that mean, "pure JavaScript doesn't have nonsensical arguments like this"? This *is* pure JavaScript, and there's nothing nonsensical about it.

Comment: its d3, you do not have these methods/functions in the native js. What I am refering to here is the fact that OP is questioning the way JS handles parameters, when in fact it is an issue isolated to a specific framework's specific method, style, in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is `d` doing here? Why is it passed when it's of no use?

The `style` function will call the callback with a specific set of arguments. The fact that the callback doesn't happen to need the first of those arguments doesn't change how `style` will call it. So the callback has to accept the argument, but then ignore it.

> From where `i` (along with value) is getting passed?

The `style` function. It's what calls the callback, so it's what determines the values of the arguments the callback receives.

Here's an example of a function accepting and calling a callback, which will probably help clarify things. See the comments:

```js
// Here's our function that accepts a callback, just like
// d3's `style` accepts a callback.
function doSomething(callback) {
  // Call the callback with two arguments,
  // a random letter and a random number:
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(26 * Math.random()));
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  callback(letter, number);
}

// Now we call that function, giving it a callback
// that makes use of both of its arguments:
doSomething(function(l, n) {
  console.log("First callback: The letter is: " + l);
  console.log("First callback: The number is: " + n);
});

// Now we call that function, giving it a callback
// that only uses the second argument:
doSomething(function(l, n) {
  console.log("Second callback: The number is: " + n);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the parameters passed to the handler functions (also known as callbacks) you provide as references.

Here's a working example:

```js
function main(a, b, callbackFn) {
  callbackFn(a * b);
}

main(2, 3, function(result) {
  console.log(result); // = 6
});
```

You can see from this that you're providing the reference of an anonymous function when you call `main()`. The anonymous function is then called from within `main()` and passed the result of the operation performed.

In some cases you may not need to do anything with the result of the operation, you simply need to execute some code when the operation has been completed - hence why your `d` variable is provided but not used.

Comment: >In some cases you may not need to do anything with the result of the operation

I didn't understood your point. Do you mean, `d` is the result of the operation and not [`datum`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633313/what-is-the-concept-behind-javascript-parameters#comment64650167_38633313)

Comment: I'm talking in general terms about the example I provided, not specifically about d3. However it would appear that the datum is always provided in d3. If you don't need to use it you still need to have your anonymous function accept that value, even if you don't use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

In D3.js, an anonymous function inside a selection gets passed three values, traditionally named `d`, `i` and `p` (more about those letters below), in that order:

1. The first value, `d`, is the datum (singular for data)
2. The second one, `i`, is the index of that datum
3. The third one is the node in D3 4.x and the parent's data index in D3 3.x.

This is how it works, click on "run code snippet":

```js
var testData = [43, 2, 57, 42, 17];

var test= d3.selectAll(".test")
    .data(testData)
    .enter()
    .append("p");
    
test.attr("foo", function(d, i) { console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(d), "\nIndex: " + JSON.stringify(i))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As the index is always the second value, you have to pass `d`, even if you don't use it.

> Can we use other letters?

The names don't matter, but only the order. Traditionally, we use "d" because it's the initial of "data", "i" because of "index" and "p" because of "parent".

Let's test:

```js
var testData = [43, 2, 57, 42, 17];

var test= d3.selectAll(".test")
    .data(testData)
    .enter()
    .append("p");
    
test.attr("foo", function(foo, bar) { console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(foo), "\nIndex: " + JSON.stringify(bar))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```